# Given a netmask, calculates the number of available hosts?

Tags: linux, go, network-programming

in Go,I find such a algorithm,but I don't understand it,can anyone explain it for me,thanks!

```
func networkSize(mask net.IPMask) int32 {
    m := net.IPv4Mask(0, 0, 0, 0)
    for i := 0; i < net.IPv4len; i++ {
        m[i] = ^mask[i]
    }

    return int32(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(m)) + 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert each bit in the netmask, treat the result as the 4 bytes of a bigendian 32-bit integer, and add 1 to the result. So 255.255.252.0 => 00000000.00000000.00000011.11111111 => 1023, adding 1 to this is 1024.

Answer (score 0):

The ip address is logical and'ed with the subnet_mask.  The subnet_mask can be used to carve out many net_id. Read here for an example: http://www.garykessler.net/library/subnet_masks.html.